# Protocol JSON (PSON) vs. Protocol Buffers

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers

After looking at the docs for [ProtoBuf.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/wiki/ProtoBuf.js-vs-JSON) I've just discovered PSON, which looks like an amazing innovation.

In the docs it says:

> PSON allows to generate an even smaller protocol than ProtoBuf, at the
>   cost of having to use it wisely.

I've just read through the [PSON docs](https://github.com/dcodeIO/PSON) and I'm not sure why the authors of the ProtoBuf.js docs say that PSON comes

> at the cost of having to use it wisely.

Can someone please explain why this is so? To my eyes, PSON looks like a  superior format to Protocol Buffers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not compatible, so useless when not adopted enough. You can transfer data between your endpoints, but if you communicate with legacy counterparts using JSON, you cannot switch to PSON instead.

Comment: There is also raw PSON decoder & encoder added to my Gason C# parser now (GitHub in my profile). Architecture and start point picked from dcodeIO/PSONSharp repo.